# Angular weird behaviour when downloading from a stream

Tags: java, angular, networking, download, stream

I have a rest controller in my Java backend to download files as a streams: end points return a StreamingResponseBody stream, when I try to download a file with curl it works fine:

```
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer <MyToken>" http://localhost:9001/rest/api/download --output test.zip
```

But not with angular, I'm using HttpModule get method:

```
this.http.get(url, headers).subscribe ...
```

However I can see that the file is being downloaded in the network panel of chrome developper tools, but I have no idea where the file is being saved, as if it was streamed instead of downloaded:

[image]

Can any body explain this behaviour, and how to download the stream intead of broadcasting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like...

```
this.http.get(`your_url`, { headers: headers, responseType: 'blob', observe: 'response'})
          .map( res => (
               {
                content: res.body, 
                fileName: res.headers.get('content-filename')
               }
           ));
```

hope this helps!